# Get posts based on meta key/value

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query

I have a custom post type "custom_author" which is selected when making a new post using a metabox dropdown with field key "chosen_author".

This is what my wp_postmeta looks like:

[image]

Where 13088 is the blog post that has "author" 13112 assigned to it.

I am trying to get all posts by a particular author using the following:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'chosen_author',
                'value' => '13112' (tried with and without quotes)
            )
        )
    );

    $getPosts = new WP_Query($args);
```

But it just returns ALL my posts.

I did some debugging:

```
$getPosts = new WP_Query($args);
echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;
```

and that output

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.post_author != 0) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Completely ignoring the meta_query array!

If it matters this being used outside the loop

Comment: `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request` isn't going to be your query since your query _isn't_ `$wp_query`, global or otherwise, it is `$getPosts`. `echo $getPosts->request` is what you want.

Comment: If you store `$getPosts` why not just `$getPosts->posts` ?

`->request` contains REQUEST aka the SQL query for your posts, not the RESULTS ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by using

get_posts($args) instead of new WP_Query($args);

No idea why...

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

It looks like  you are saving the data as:

```
$a = array( "13112" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, "article_author", $a);
```

where this will give you the `meta_value`

```
a:1:{i:0;s:5:"13112";}
```

Your first query will give you escaped quotes:

```
LIKE '%\"13112\"%'
```

### Method 1

If you save the author array with numbers instead:

```
$a = array( 13112 );
update_post_meta( $post_id, "article_author", $a);
```

then the corresponding  `meta_value` will be

```
a:1:{i:0;i:13112;}
```

So when you try the meta query:

```
 'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'article_author',
                'value' => ':13112;',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
    )
```

the corresponding SQL part will be

```
LIKE '%:13112;%'
```

You could try to use this instead.

### Method 2

Another way is to remove the escaped quotes with non-escaped quotes:

```
add_filter('posts_where','my_posts_where');
$getPosts = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_where','my_posts_where');
```

where

```
function my_posts_where($where){    
    $where = str_replace('\"', '"', $where);    
    return $where;  
}
```

but I don't reccomend it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I don't have much control over the format saving (string/integer), out of interest, why does it return all posts if it clearly can't find a match? How am I supposed to handle no matching posts found if it returns all my posts? Edit: OK it doesn't return ALL my posts but it does return 100s

Comment: yes, that's strange, when you search in PHPMyAdmin, do you get similiar results?

Comment: I was using a plugin to help me with custom meta boxes (a drop down of my custom post type entries). I've dived in and did it all myself in functions.php and now I save in the db just the number as the meta_value: 13112 Still no joy though, I'll see if I can turn on some sort of debugging that outputs the SQL query it is attempting to perform.

Comment: Weird, I used $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; to find out and it outputted `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.post_author != 0) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10` completely ignoring the meta_query!!

Comment: I've updated my original question with a more up to date summary

Comment: Fixed below (sorry for the spam!)

Comment: ok good to hear you found a way around your problem ;-) You should check your SQL with `$getPosts->request` instead.